# LCDproc screen timeout

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lcd

I am having an issue with LCDproc, using the python package here http://pydoc.net/Python/lcdproc/0.03/lcdproc.server/

Quick background - I am parsing airplay metadata from a pipe and displaying it on an lcd screen as a part of a Raspberry Pi music player project.
I'd like to display a screen when the user changes the playback volume. I thought the way to do this was to add a new screen and set a timeout. This works the first time, and subsequently causes an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lcdtunes.py", line 194, in <module>
    main()
  File "./lcdtunes.py", line 147, in main
    vol_screen.set_heartbeat("off")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_heartbeat'
```

The script is available here: https://github.com/john-a-harris/lcdtunes/blob/master/lcdtunes.py

I am no coder, as will be obvious, but I think that the error means that the screen I think I am adding in line 146 doesn't actually exist.

My question is why - what am I doing wrong here?
Is there another way to achieve this or am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Please be gentle with me - this is my first question!